# Imaging library to display yuv data in C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, yuv

I was wondering is there any C++ imaging libraries so that I can take a yuv file and display it, I will be able to pass the resolution of the file and Ycbcr info(usually at 4:2:2) I need this to turn the yuv into jpegs if possible or to display it in rgb mode to be built on a QPixmap. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked around, did you tried the following ?

http://code.google.com/p/yuvtoolkit

http://code.google.com/p/yuvplayer

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll definitely have a look into that. I can use the source code because my project is open source and the licenses won't conflict.